# Parsing Array in the stdClass Object Array form

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array(
    [0] => stdClass Object(
        [key] => VALID
        [value] => Y
    )
    [1] => stdClass Object(
        [key] => YEAR
        [value] => 2018 
    )
)
```

I need to parse the Array and need to use the valu e of VALID and YEAR.Tried to use a for loop as key value pair.Since each loop having more than 1 key-value pair,I don't know to proceed.

```
foreach($value as $key1 => $value1) {
  print_r($value1); 
}
```

This is the code used to display the above data.

I tried this:

```
foreach($value as $key1 => $value1) {
  foreach($value1 as $key2 => $value2) {
       print_r($value2);
  } 
}
```

Which outputted : `VALIDYYEAR2018`

```
foreach($value as $key1 => $value1) {
  foreach($value1 as $key2 => $value2) {
       print_r($key2);
  } 
}
```

Which outputted : `keyvaluekeyvalue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an array from your data, with the keys being `VALID` and `YEAR` and the appropriate values with them:

```
$value = array((object)['key' => 'VALID', 'value' => 'Y'], 
               (object)['key' => 'YEAR', 'value' => 2018]);
$data = array();
foreach ($value as $v) {
    $data[$v->key] = $v->value;
}
print_r($data);
```

Output

```
Array ( 
    [VALID] => Y
    [YEAR] => 2018 
)
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/jTZ1P)

Answer (score 1):

The `print_r` output isn't showing you an "array form" that you need to "parse"; it's showing you that you have two objects, whose [properties](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) you want to access.

Access to those properties would look like this:

```
foreach ( $list as $item ) {
    // $item is an object with two properties
    $key = $item->key;
    $value = $item->value;
    // Do whatever you need with those two properties
}
```